# Why mouse event cannot be captured at the border of a Chrome app window?

Tags: google-chrome-app

Using a Chrome app window with frame set to 'none', it seems that mouse events are only being triggered when the pointer is within the grey area.

The 'blue' border illustrates 3 pixels of 'padding' where no mouse events are captured.

Hence we cannot capture mouse position at for example 0,0 or 1,1 or 2,2 .. and so on.

I am currently testing on Windows 8 , not sure if this issue is platform specific.

[image: Chrome Packaged App Window Illustration]

**Update:**

A bug has been filed at:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=307942

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a bug, file it as one at http://crbug.com/new. Link it here and others can star it to receive updates on it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have filed a bug in Chromium.